# Android Silent Mode Toggle

Tags: android

I started reading Android for dummies and I am trying to make my first app that is Silent Mode Toggle.

Now the problem I'm facing is:

In the layout, I need something like only one button should be there. If the phone is on silent the text should read "Silent Mode Activated" and when the phone is in normal mode "Normal Mode Activated".

It should ask the user that He/She wants to activate vibration mode or not.

Below is my code :

**XML Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >    

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phone_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_on" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/silent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/silent_off" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        setButtonClickListener();
        Log.d("SilentModeApp", "This is a test");
    }    

    private void setButtonClickListener() {
        Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.silent);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
                    //change back to normal mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //change to silent mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                }
                // Now toggle the UI again
                toggleUi(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
        int ringermode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
        if (ringermode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        }
    }

    private void toggleUi() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        Drawable newPhoneImage;
        if (mPhoneIsSilent){
            newPhoneImage = 
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);
        }
        else
        {
            newPhoneImage = 
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);

        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
    }

    @Override      
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        toggleUi();
    }
}
```

**Update**

Now I removed "mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); " and its going to vibration mode from normal mode.

I need help with the layout thing.

I need 3 buttons and a text status text - I know how to create buttons and text message, what I dont know is how to integrate it with java.

I need if the phone is in normal mode there should be a status message below image above buttons : (XXX MODE IS ACTIVATED ) where XXX is Silent, Normal Or Vibrate.

The if the phone is in normal mode then there should be only 2 buttons : Switch to silent mode and Switch to vibration mode.

And the same thing with other modes too.

Comment: You told us what the you want to achieve, you provided the code but you didn't really tell what is wrong it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this code. Its fully working. I just removed this line "mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); " and now its shifting from normal mode to silent mode with vibration. So one problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a textview that says whether silent mode is/isnt activated? ie just a small bit of text near a button, that shows status? And your buttons to dynamically appear/dissapear as well?

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.relevanttextview); //text above button/wherever
Button bt = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.relevantbutton); //button to make appear/dissapear 

if(vibrate is on){
tv.setText("vibrate is on");
bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //make button appear
}

if(normal mode is on){
tv.setText("normal");
bt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //make button dissapear
}
```

etc...

Comment: No I want something else. I want that there will be total 3 buttons in XML and 1 for normal mode, 1 for silent nd 1 for silent with vibration.

Comment: Then define two more buttons in your XML file...?

Answer (score 0):

```
AndriodManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>


package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import static android.app.NotificationManager.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AudioManager audioManager;
    //private int CAMREA_CODE = 1;

    private int MOD_ADO_CODE=1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private StatusBarNotification[] mText;
    private int MZenMode;
    private static final String TAG = "ZenModeObserver";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FrameLayout contentView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        contentView.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //RingerHelper.performToggle(audioManager);
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Policy, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            MZenMode=logZenModeState();
                        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (MZenMode==2)
                            changeInterruptionFiler(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
                        else
                            changeInterruptionFiler(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
                        updateUi();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    private void updateUi() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        int phoneImage = MZenMode==2?R.drawable.ringer_off : R.drawable.ringer_on;
        //int phoneImage = RingerHelper.isPhoneSilent(audioManager) ? R.drawable.ringer_off : R.drawable.ringer_on;
        imageView.setImageResource(phoneImage);
    }

    protected void changeInterruptionFiler(int interruptionFilter) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
                mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(interruptionFilter);

            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private int logZenModeState() throws Settings.SettingNotFoundException {
        int zenModeValue = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), "zen_mode");
        return zenModeValue;
    }

    private class ZenModeObserver extends ContentObserver {

        ZenModeObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }
    }
        @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        updateUi();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sanjib, thanks for your answer. Can you add some explanation on how your code solves the problem?

Comment: Actually most of the answers i got in the internet forgot to mention the permission- which is nessary after Ver 23. So we added the permision in Manifast file. Then get the current status in "zenmode"